# How to handle Hyperopt AssertionError in adaptive_parzen_normal?

Tags: python, neural-network, hyperparameters, hyperopt

I am using hyperopt to search over a space to help tune the hyperparamters of a neural network.  The space I am searching over is:

```
space = {
    'latent_dim1': hp.qloguniform('latent_dim1', np.log(30), np.log(70), 1),

    'batch_size': hp.choice('batch_size', [32, 64, 128]),

    'epochs': hp.choice('epochs', [150, 200, 250, 300]),

    'optimiser': hp.choice('optimizer', ['adam', 'rmsprop', COCOB()]),
    'learning_rates': hp.loguniform('learning_rates', np.log(0.1), np.log(0.001)),

    'loss': hp.choice('loss', ['mean_absolute_error', diff_smape]),

    'window': hp.choice('window', [True, False]),
    'window_size': hp.quniform('window_size', 13, 104, 1),

    'teacher_forcing': hp.choice('teacher_forcing', [True, False])
}
```

When searching over this space, after ten to twenty space iterations I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hyperparam_gru.py", line 159, in <module>
    best = fmin(seq2seq_model_gru, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100, trials=trials)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 367, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin,
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 635, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 385, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 244, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.asynchronous)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 202, in run
    self.rstate.randint(2 ** 31 - 1))
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/tpe.py", line 901, in suggest
    print_node_on_error=False)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/pyll/base.py", line 913, in rec_eval
    rval = scope._impls[node.name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/tpe.py", line 466, in adaptive_parzen_normal
    assert prior_sigma > 0
AssertionError
```

I was able to search over a less expressive space fine (and over other spaces):

```
space= {
    'latent_dim1': hp.choice('latent_dim1', [30, 50, 70, 90]),

    'batch_size': hp.choice('batch_size', [16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]),

    'epochs': hp.choice('epochs', [100, 150, 200, 250]),

    'optimiser': hp.choice('optimizer', ['adadelta', 'adam', 'rmsprop', COCOB()]),
    'learning_rates': hp.choice('learning_rates', [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]),

    'loss': hp.choice('loss', ['mean_absolute_error', diff_smape]),

    'window': hp.choice('window', [True, False]),
    'window_size': hp.choice('window_size', [13, 26, 39, 52, 78, 104]),

    'teacher_forcing': hp.choice('teacher_forcing', [True, False])
}
```

I am not sure how to handle the error?  Ideally I would like it just to omit whatever combination of the hyperparameters is causing the problem and just move on to the next combination to try.  At the moment however the error just terminates the program.